# rails get record that is not exist on right join

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am trying to get a query for a join table, where the record in right table is nonexistent, for a specific param.

Let say that a user should post email every day, and the email model will be created with a date. I want to get users who did not post an email on a specific day.

I tried using [not exist and also not in](https://blog.udemy.com/sql-not-exists/) but to no avail. Or maybe my syntax is incorrect or I am missing something.

```
User.joins(:emails).where("emails.date not in ('2021-01-24') and emails.id is null)
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know  Ruby-on-rails, but it looks like `and emails.id is null` should be `OR emails.id is null`

Comment: OR didnt work because it will pull all the records with date other than the specified '2021-01-24'

Comment: `joins` creates `INNER JOIN` it's not right join as you wrote in the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try from different angle:

```
date = Date.parse('2021-01-24')
user_ids = Email.where(date: date).pluck(:user_id)
User.where.not(id: user_ids)
```

Comment: thanks this works. really need to think the problem from different angle.